# Calculate area module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a module that calculates the area of shapes and I wanted to get feedback. Am I on the right track?

```
import math

# A python program to calculate the area of shapes


# area of a square is length multiplied by width
def area_of_square(length, width):
    _check_if_values_are_strings(length = length, width = width)
    _check_if_values_are_negitive(lenth = length, width = width)

    return length * width

# area of a triangle is base multiplied by height divided by 2
def area_of_triangle(base_value, height):
    _check_if_values_are_strings(base_value = base_value, height = height)
    _check_if_values_are_negitive(base_value = base_value, height = height)

    return (base_value * height) / 2

# area of a circle is radius squared times pi
def area_of_circle(radius):
    _check_if_values_are_strings(radius = radius)
    _check_if_values_are_negitive(radius = radius)

    return math.pow(radius,2) * math.pi


def _check_if_values_are_strings(**values):
    for k,v in values.items():
        if (isinstance(v,str)):
            raise TypeError("{0} is a string".format(k))

def _check_if_values_are_negitive(**values):
    for k,v in values.items():
        if v < 0:
            raise ValueError("{0} is a negitive".format(k))
```

My main concern is the use of the `_check_if_values_are_strings` and `_check_if_values_are_negitive` methods. Am I using them correctly, or is there a better approach to verifying the parameters before preforming the calculation?

Comment: Doesn't affect the code, but "negitive" should be spelled "negative"

Comment: (Welcome to CR!) (Should affect the code: `lenth = length`.) Not using any keyword in "the checks", *why* are you not using a single asterisk (*args* instead of *kwargs*)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having multiple **`_check_if_values_are_`something**s, just have a single check for the type of values you want. You want the values to be positive real number, just assert them:

```
def ensure_positive_reals(*values):
    assert all(val >= 0 for val in values)
```

which will raise `ValueError` if any of the `val` was a string and an `AssertionError` if any of them is negative (Thanks [Mathias](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/188925/calculate-area-module/188946?noredirect=1#comment361136_188946)). To use it, you have:

```
ensure_positive_reals(radius)
ensure_positive_reals(length, width)
ensure_positive_reals(base_value, height)
```

---

Instead of `math.pow`, use the exponentiation expression `**`:

```
math.pi * (radius ** 2)
```

[which is faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20970087/1190388).

Comment: Except `float(val)` will not error out on a string like `"42"` but then `area_of_square("42", 2)` will return `'4242'` instead of the expected `84`… Why not just use `assert all(val >= 0 for val in values)` instead and let Python tell you about `TypeError`s if any `val` is not a number?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger ah yes. I didn't notice that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

A few things:

1. Squares don't have width and height, those are rectangles
2. You check to see that your values are not `string`s, what if they are `list`s (or other types of objects)?
3. Your check functions error if their title is true, this is unintuitive. Something like `ensure_value_is_positive` would be a better name.